# Append an array to each list item in separate ul's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add the contents of an array to every list on the page by appending 1 through 4 to the list items. The problem I'm having is that I can't do this to every list, and if their is only 3 list items, I don't want to add another item, just end the list at 3. I'd also like to remove the 0s.

Thanks in advance!

```js
var levels = [ "1", "2", "3", "4" ];
$('ul li').each(function (x) {
 $(this).append(levels[x]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li>0</li>
 <li>0</li>
 <li>0</li>
 <li>0</li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li>0</li>
 <li>0</li>
 <li>0</li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li>0</li>
 <li>0</li>
 <li>0</li>
 <li>0</li>
</ul>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7ESKh/221/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the lists first, and then iterate over the list items for each list

```
var levels = [ "1", "2", "3", "4" ];

$('ul').each(function(i, ul) {
    $(ul).find('li').each(function(j, li) {
        $(this).html(levels[j]);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7ESKh/224/)

Comment: Thank you, how would I remove the 0s also?

Comment: @Lukas - So you don't want to append, you want to replace ?

Comment: Yes, sorry I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[`:nth-child()`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)** and **[`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)**

```js
var levels = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
$.each(levels, function(i, x) {
  $('ul li:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')').html(x);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>0</li>
  <li>0</li>
  <li>0</li>
  <li>0</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>0</li>
  <li>0</li>
  <li>0</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>0</li>
  <li>0</li>
  <li>0</li>
  <li>0</li>
</ul>
```